# Ollydbg target runs automatically

Tags: debugging, portable-executable, entry-point, ollydbg

I have a target that automatically runs after I load it in to Ollydbg. 
This form, doesn't stop at the entry point (but continues to execute and at a point it pauses, I have to press shift + f9.)

Is there any way to debug it??

Answer (score 2):

The target is probably loading before the entry point, usually a tls.
Use the NtGlobalFlag plugin to do this. It works by setting the FLG_SHOW_LDR_SNAPS flag.

btw this belongs in the rce stackexchange, not stackoverflow.